# In SQL Server, in which case the query plan contain <ParameterList> tag?

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I'm using the following query for taking the query plans from the SQL Server database:

```
SELECT st.text as parameterized_query,[qp].[query_plan]
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text ( cp.plan_handle ) st 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan ( cp.plan_handle ) qp
```

---

1. I find that in case I'm using `DECLARE` and `SET` in a query, then:

   1.1. `parameterized_query` is something like: `DECLARE @p1 INT; SET @p1 = 1; SELECT * FROM a WHERE ID > @p1`

   1.2. `query_plan` **not contain** `<ParameterList>` tag.
2. In some other cases (which i don`t understand):

   2.1. `parameterized_query` is something like: `(@p1 INT)SELECT * FROM a WHERE ID > @p1`

   2.2. `query_plan` **contain** `<ParameterList>` tag.

When case 2 is happen?

Comment: The 2nd case happens with the application is binding variables to the parameters (similarly as passing parameters to stored procedures).

Answer (score 0):

If `AUTO PARAMETERIZATION` is set to ON, SQL Server will compile some queries using parameters, the values passed in at compile time are listed in the  tag.

You may find this link useful:
http://www.benjaminnevarez.com/2010/06/auto-parameterization-in-sql-server/